# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widget'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am getting runtime sever error while running the command `python manage.py runserver`. The Terminal is showing errors:
line 35, in CustomertaskForm,startdate=forms.DateInput(widget=forms.DateField()) TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widget'

forms.py

```
class CustomertaskForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomertaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    title=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'required': 'required'}))
    discription=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'required': 'required'}))
    startdate=forms.DateInput(widget=forms.DateField())
    enddate=forms.DateInput(widget=forms.DateField())

    class Meta:
        model=Customertask
        fields=['title','discription','startdate','enddate']
```

models.py

```
class Customertask(models.Model):
   title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
   discription=models.CharField(max_length=500)
   startdate=models.DateTimeField()
   enddate=models.DateTimeField()
```

view.py

```
def createtasks(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form=CustomertaskForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        tasksave=Customertask.objects.create(
            customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer)
            title=form.cleaned_data['title'],
            discription = form.cleaned_data['discription'],
            startdate=form.cleaned_data['startdate'],
            enddate=form.cleaned_data['enddate']
        )
        tasksave.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/customer/tasktable')
else:
    form=CustomertaskForm()
return render(request, 'customer/createtasks.html', {'form': form})
```

is it Important to migrate, each time changes in models.py or forms.py....please gime a clear comment on the migration.

Comment: Please post the *entire* traceback when you ask questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this in your form.
>
> Forms.py

```
        widgets = {
        'Title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','required':'required'}),
        'Description': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','required':'required'}),
        'StartDate': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'date','required':'required'}),
        'EndDate': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'date','required':'required'}),
       }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have your widgets and fields the wrong way around - `DateField` is a field and `DateInput` is a widget. So your form use `forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput())`. However, since `DateField` uses `DateInput` by default, you can drop the widget argument entirely:

```
class CustomertaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    startdate=forms.DateField()
    enddate=forms.DateField()
```

As an aside, you can create the task by saving the model form. You don't need to call `Customertask.objects.create()` manually:

```
if form.is_valid():
    tasksave=form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/customer/tasktable')
```